# Autofill data in 2nd column based on rows in another column

Tags: vba, excel, autofill

I have been searching and searching and tried a couple of ideas but have not gotten this working yet. I am thinking I may need to use a VB script to do this but all attempts so far have failed.

Essentially, I need to autofill cells in a second column with the same data that is in that first row in column 2 (i.e. in screenshot B2 = '234', so all cells below would also be '234').  The rows of data in column 2 filldown should match the total number of rows that are in column A (which may change from one job to the next).  I've tried editing several formulas that were close from here on Stack but I keep getting errors. I'm attaching a screenshot in the hopes this will make it more clear and would really appreciate any insight into this.  Thanks. 
SCREENSHOT-autfill column 2 based on numbers of rows in column 1

[image]

Comment: Have you tried recording a macro?

Comment: Yes, but the macro only works to have it autofill for the number of rows for that particular time.  When I add another couple of rows in column

Comment: Frustrating, because I'm new it doesn't allow me to edit my comment above. Here is the finished version:  Yes, but the macro only works to have it autofill for the number of rows for that particular time.  When I add another couple of rows in column 1 and try to run the Macro again, it only fills column 2 to the same place as before (i.e. leaving the last two rows blank).

Comment: You need to post your current code so we can help "debug" it.  What you need is a variable "LastRow".

Comment: Okay, this was the only way I could get it to work:    Sub ClientFill()
'
' ClientFill Macro
'

'
Dim lngLastRow As Long
lngLastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    Range("B3:B" & lngLastRow).Value = Evaluate("B2")
End Sub

Comment: Now, I'm trying to do something similar in the next column using 'Concatenate'  but keep getting a syntax error. Should I post that as a separate question?

Comment: I just posted the second half as a different question since I think it's a separate syntax question. Thanks for trying to help and I'm sorry I cannot get my working answer to format better. I seem to be limited in what I can do as a new user.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Trying to post the answer so it's formatted better.

```
Sub ClientFill() 
' 
' 
ClientFill Macro 
' 
' 
Dim lngLastRow As Long lngLastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row     
Range("B3:B" & lngLastRow).Value = Evaluate("B2") 
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for editing that Christmas007.  I figured out what I was doing wrong for the 'code indents'.